# AEM Failing to resolve dependencies for maven project

Tags: maven, aem

I'm trying to get our project up and running locally. I'm running the following command at the root level of our project `mvn clean install -Plocal -PautoInstallPackage` and getting the error:

> Failed to execute goal on project act-bundle: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.wcm.act:act-bundle:bundle:2.1.30: Failed to collect dependencies at io.wcm:io.wcm.t
> esting.aem-mock.junit4:jar:2.4.8 -> io.wcm:io.wcm.testing.aem-mock.core:jar:2.4.8 -> org.apache.commons:commons-imaging:jar:1.0-R1534292

I am using AEM 6.5, Maven 3.9.2, Java 8, Windows

Here is my full POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven- 
v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.wcm.act</groupId>
<artifactId>act</artifactId>
<version>2.1.30</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>Act Redesign AEM</name>
<description>Maven Multimodule project for Our Project</description>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.9.2</maven>
</prerequisites>

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!-- P R O P E R T I E S -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<properties>
    <!-- Encoding -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Versions -->
    <com.adobe.aem.uber-jar.version>6.5.17</com.adobe.aem.uber-jar.version>
    <com.citrix.gototraining-api.version>0.11.0</com.citrix.gototraining-api.version>
    <com.citrix.goto-core-lib.version>0.10.0</com.citrix.goto-core-lib.version>
    <com.cognifide.cq.sling-dynamic-include.version>2.0.4</com.cognifide.cq.sling-dynamic-include.version>
    <com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations.version>2.13.1</com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations.version>
    <com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core.version>2.13.1</com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core.version>
    <com.google.code.gson.version>2.8.9</com.google.code.gson.version>
    <com.google.guava.version>12.0</com.google.guava.version>
    <com.restfb.version>1.9.0</com.restfb.version>
    <com.squareup.okhttp3>3.10.0</com.squareup.okhttp3>
    <com.squareup.okio>1.14.0</com.squareup.okio>
    <com.sun.jersey.jersey-bundle.version>1.19.1</com.sun.jersey.jersey-bundle.version>
    <com.sun.xml.parsers.jaxp-ri.version>1.4.5</com.sun.xml.parsers.jaxp-ri.version>
    <com.tinify>1.5.1</com.tinify>
    <commons-httpclient.version>3.1</commons-httpclient.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
    <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
    <felix.scr.version>1.6.2</felix.scr.version>
    <felix.scr.annotations.version>1.9.0</felix.scr.annotations.version>
    <io.wcm.sling.commons.version>1.2.4</io.wcm.sling.commons.version>
    <io.wcm.testing.aem-mock.version>2.4.8</io.wcm.testing.aem-mock.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
    <javax.jcr.version>2.0</javax.jcr.version>
    <javax.servlet.servlet-api.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet.servlet-api.version>
    <jaxen.version>1.1.4</jaxen.version>
    <joda-time.version>1.6</joda-time.version>
    <junit-addons.version>1.4</junit-addons.version>
    <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
    <org.apache.commons.commons-lang3.version>3.12.0</org.apache.commons.commons-lang3.version>
    <org.apache.commons.commons-email.version>1.1</org.apache.commons.commons-email.version>
    <org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.version>1.6.0</org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.version>
    <org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient.version>4.0.3</org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient.version>
    <org.apache.sling.models.api.version>1.3.6</org.apache.sling.models.api.version>
    <org.apache.sling.junit.core.version>1.0.26</org.apache.sling.junit.core.version>
    <org.apache.sling.junit.scriptable.version>1.0.12</org.apache.sling.junit.scriptable.version>
    <org.codehaus.jettison.version>1.3.1</org.codehaus.jettison.version>
    <org.hamcrest.hamcrest-all.version>1.3</org.hamcrest.hamcrest-all.version>
    <org.mockito.mockito-all.version>2.27.0</org.mockito.mockito-all.version>
    <org.powermock.powermock-module-junit4.version>2.0.2</org.powermock.powermock-module-junit4.version>
    <org.powermock.powermock-api-mockito.version>2.0.2</org.powermock.powermock-api-mockito.version>
    <org.osgi.core.version>6.0.0</org.osgi.core.version>
    <org.osgi.compendium.version>6.0.0</org.osgi.compendium.version>
    <com.jcraft.jsch.version>0.1.53</com.jcraft.jsch.version>
    <org.jdom.version>2.0.2</org.jdom.version>
    <org.jsoup.version>1.7.1</org.jsoup.version>
    <org.slf4j.slf4j-api.version>1.7.21</org.slf4j.slf4j-api.version>
    <org.twitter4j.twitter4j-core.version>[4.0,)</org.twitter4j.twitter4j-core.version>
    <rome.version>0.9</rome.version>
    <xerces.version>2.8.0</xerces.version>

    <!-- Directories -->
    <rootdir>${project.basedir}</rootdir>
    <checkstyle.root>${rootdir}/build-config/checkstyle</checkstyle.root>
    <pmd.root>${rootdir}/build-config/pmd</pmd.root>
    <project.reporting.outputDirectory />

    <project.groupId>com.wcm.act</project.groupId>
    <project.version>2.1.11-SNAPSHOT</project.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- ********************************************* -->
        <!-- Core Dependencies -->
        <!-- ********************************************* -->
        <!-- Adobe AEM Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
            <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
            <version>${com.adobe.aem.uber-jar.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- OSGi Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.osgi.core.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.annotation</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.cmpn</artifactId>
            <version>${org.osgi.compendium.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.slf4j-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JCR -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.jcr.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ********************************************* -->
        <!-- Custom Code Dependencies -->
        <!-- ********************************************* -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>${org.jsoup.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.commons.commons-lang3.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.commons.commons-email.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-httpclient.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>                     <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>rome</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>${rome.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tinify</groupId>
            <artifactId>tinify</artifactId>
            <version>${com.tinify}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>${com.squareup.okhttp3}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
            <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
            <version>${com.squareup.okio}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.221</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<!-- Inclusion of repositories in POMs is controversial, to say the least. 
    It would be best if you proxied the Adobe repository using a Maven Repository 
    Manager. Once you do that, remove these sections. -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache</id>
        <name>Apache Public Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>apache-snapshot</id>
        <name>Apache Public Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>adobe-repo</id>
        <name>Adobe Public Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>adobe</id>
        <name>Adobe Public Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>${checkstyle.root}/act-checks.xml</configLocation>
                <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                <skip>true</skip>
                <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
                <suppressionsLocation>${checkstyle.root}/checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
                <suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.file</suppressionsFileExpression>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/reports/checkstyle</outputDirectory>
                <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/reports/checkstyle/checkstyle-result.xml</outputFile>
                <outputFileFormat>xml</outputFileFormat>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>${pmd.root}/act-pmd.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
                <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/reports/pmd</targetDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/reports/pmd</outputDirectory>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-java</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireJavaVersion>
                                <message>Project must be compiled with Java 8</message>
                                <version>${java.version}</version>
                            </requireJavaVersion>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <username>${cq.username}</username>
                    <password>${cq.password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.20</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    <username>${cq.username}</username>
                    <password>${cq.password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.felix
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-scr-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.0.0,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>scr</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>env.type</name>
                <value>local</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <cq.host>http://localhost</cq.host>
            <cq.port>4502</cq.port>
            <cq.user>admin</cq.user>
            <cq.password>admin</cq.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>local-publish</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <cq.host>http://localhost</cq.host>
            <cq.port>4503</cq.port>
            <cq.user>admin</cq.user>
            <cq.password>admin</cq.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>autoInstallPackage</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                        <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install-package</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <targetURL>${cq.host}:${cq.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp?force=true</targetURL>
                                    <userId>${cq.user}</userId>
                                    <password>${cq.password}</password>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<modules>
    <module>act-bundle</module>
    <module>act-config</module>
    <module>act-ui</module>
    <module>act-dispatcher</module>
</modules>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: Can you share the other pom files? I do not see this dependency being used here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading from [maven central repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging/1.0-R1534292), it seems this version doesn't contains a jar file. You can fix it by manually set [a specific version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging) of this artifact in dependencyManagement tag in your project pom. Or if it is an unnecessary transitive dependency, you can also manually exclude it.

If you are using a private or specific maven artifact repo, you should go to the repo and search this artifact to see if exist or not, or whether there is an alternative version.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just needed to fix my JAVA_HOME path to JDK instead of JRE. Thanks for the ideas everyone!